# Syntax Error when using the source command in MySql

Tags: mariadb, syntax-error

I have some tables that will not be made when using the source command and I can't seem to find out what is wrong with them

I used MariaDB [cpt238]> source E:\database\create.sql

and got this

MariaDB [cpt238]> source E:\database\create.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.028 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.017 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.012 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.013 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.014 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.017 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.017 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.023 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.015 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.012 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.016 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.016 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.014 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.016 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.017 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.007 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 122 in file: 'E:\database\create.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table Credential(
CRD_ID int not null auto_increment,
CRD_Title varcha...' at line 5
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.014 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.017 sec)

ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 156 in file: 'E:\database\create.sql': Can't create table `cpt238`.`student` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 164 in file: 'E:\database\create.sql': Can't create table `cpt238`.`graduation` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 174 in file: 'E:\database\create.sql': Can't create table `cpt238`.`requirement` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.021 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.020 sec)

ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 208 in file: 'E:\database\create.sql': Can't create table `cpt238`.`fulfillment` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.018 sec)

This is the source file:

```
create table State(
Sta_Abbr char(2),
Sta_Name varchar(25) not null,
primary key (Sta_Abbr)
);

create table Zipcode(
Zip_Zipcode varchar(10) not null,
Zip_City varchar(25) not null,
Sta_Abbr char(2) not null,
primary key (Zip_Zipcode),
foreign key (Sta_Abbr) references State(Sta_Abbr)
);

create table Gender(
Gen_Gender char(1) not null,
Gen_Desc varchar(6) not null,
primary key (Gen_Gender)
);

create table Person(
Per_ID int not null auto_increment,
Per_FirstName varchar(15) not null,
Per_LastName varchar(15) not null,
Gen_Gender char(1) not null,
Per_DOB int not null,
primary key (Per_ID),
foreign key (Gen_Gender) references Gender(Gen_Gender)
);

create table ConType (
CT_ID int not null auto_increment,
CT_Desc varchar(20) not null,
primary key (CT_ID)
);

create table Phone(
Pho_ID int not null auto_increment,
Pho_Area int(3),
Pho_Exchange int(3) not null,
Pho_Extension int(4) not null,
CT_ID int not null,
primary key (pho_id),
foreign key (CT_ID) references ConType(CT_ID)
);

create table Email(
Mail_ID int not null auto_increment,
Mail_Domain varchar(10) not null,
Mail_UserName varchar(20) not null,
CT_ID int not null,
primary key (Mail_ID),
foreign key (CT_ID) references ConType(CT_ID)
);

create table Address(
Add_ID int not null auto_increment,
Sta_Abbr char(2) not null,
Zip_ZipCode varchar(15) not null,
CT_ID int not null,
primary key (Add_ID),
foreign key (Sta_Abbr) references State(Sta_Abbr),
foreign key (Zip_ZipCode) references Zipcode(Zip_Zipcode),
foreign key (CT_ID) references ConType(CT_ID)
);

create table DegType (
DT_ID int not null auto_increment,
DT_Title varchar(15) not null,
DT_Level int not null,
DT_Abbr char(4),
primary key (DT_ID)
);

create table Grade (
Grd_Sym char(2) not null,
Grd_Desc varchar(20) not null,
Grd_Credit boolean not null,
Grd_Pts int not null,
Grd_GPA boolean not null,
primary key (Grd_Sym)
);

create table Term(
Trm_Num int(2) not null,
Trm_Desc varchar(10) not null,
Trm_Length int not null,
primary key (Trm_Num)
);

create table Year(
Yr_Year int(4) not null,
primary key (Yr_Year)
);

create table Semester(
Sem_ID int not null auto_increment,
Trm_Num int(2) not null,
Yr_Year int(4) not null,
Sem_Start Date not null,
Sem_End Date not null,
primary key (Sem_ID),
foreign key (Yr_Year) references Year(Yr_Year),
foreign key (Trm_Num) references Term(Trm_Num)
);

create table Department(
Dpt_ID int not null auto_increment,
Dpt_Name varchar(35) not null,
primary key (Dpt_ID)
);

create table Faculty(
Per_ID int(4) not null,
Dpt_ID int(4) not null,
Primary key (Per_ID),
foreign key (Per_ID) references Person(Per_ID),
foreign key (Dpt_ID) references Department(Dpt_ID)
);

Alter table Department add Per_ID int not null;
Alter table Department add foreign key (Per_ID) references Faculty(Per_ID);



create table Credential(
CRD_ID int not null auto_increment,
CRD_Title varchar(25) not null,
DT_ID int not null,
CRD_Yr int(4) not null,
DPT_ID int not null,
primary key (CRD_ID),
foreign key (DT_ID) references DegType(DT_ID),
foreign key (Dpt_ID) references Department(Dpt_ID)
);

create table Subject(
Sub_Abbr char(3) not null,
Sub_Name varchar(25) not null,
DPT_ID int not null,
primary key (Sub_Abbr),
foreign key (DPT_ID) references Department(DPT_ID)
);

create table Course(
Crs_ID int not null auto_increment,
Crs_Num int(3) not null,
Sub_Abbr char(3) not null,
Crs_Desc varchar(200),
Crs_Title varchar(25) not null,
Crs_Hrs int(2) not null,
primary key (Crs_ID),
foreign key (Sub_Abbr) references Subject(Sub_Abbr)
);

create table Student(
Per_ID int not null,
CRD_ID int not null,
primary key (Per_ID),
foreign key (Per_ID) references Person(Per_ID),
foreign key (CRD_ID) references Credential(CRD_ID)
); 

create table Graduation(
Grad_ID int not null auto_increment,
Per_ID int not null,
CRD_ID int not null,
Grad_Date Date not null,
primary key (Grad_ID),
foreign key (Per_ID) references Student(Per_ID),
foreign key (CRD_ID) references Credential(CRD_ID)
);

create table Requirement(
Req_ID int not null auto_increment,
CRD_ID int not null,
Crs_ID int not null,
primary key (Req_ID),
foreign key (CRD_ID) references Credential(CRD_ID),
foreign key (Crs_ID) references Course(Crs_ID)
);

create table Section(
Sec_ID int not null auto_increment,
Sec_Num int(3) not null,
Crs_ID int(3) not null,
Per_ID int not null,
Trm_Num int(2) not null,
Yr_Year int(4) not null,
primary key (Sec_ID),
foreign key (Crs_ID) references Course(Crs_ID),
foreign key (Per_ID) references Faculty(Per_ID),
foreign key (Trm_Num) references Term(Trm_Num),
foreign key (Yr_Year) references Year(Yr_Year)
);

create table Completion(
Cmp_ID int not null auto_increment,
Per_ID int not null,
Sec_ID int not null,
Grd_Sym char(2) not null,
primary key (Cmp_ID),
foreign key (Per_ID) references Person (Per_ID),
foreign key (Sec_ID) references Section (Sec_ID),
foreign key (Grd_Sym) references Grade (Grd_Sym)
);

create table Fulfillment(
Ful_ID int not null auto_increment,
Req_ID int not null,
Cmp_ID int not null,
primary key (Ful_ID),
foreign key (Req_ID) references Requirement(Req_ID),
foreign key (Cmp_ID) references Completion(Cmp_ID)
);

create table PreReq(
Prq_ID int not null auto_increment,
Crs_ID int(3) not null,
Prq_Crs_ID int(3) not null,
primary key (Prq_ID),
foreign key (Crs_ID) references Course(Crs_ID),
foreign key (Prq_Crs_ID) references Course(Crs_ID)
);
```

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using? Your create SQL worked fine using version 10.7.7.

Comment: I'm not really sure our professor asked us to download XAMPP and MySql was included in that. The XAMPP version is v3.3.0